# Visual Studio 2013 c# web forms not visible

Tags: c#, bi-tool

I have installed 
en_visual_studio_ultimate_2013_x86_dvd on windows 10.
and SQL server Business Intelligence data tools . 
now i getting only Analysis and Integration and reports package in New Project options in visual studio .

when i uninstall visual studio and again install VS , VS C# create new projects visible but not integration package. 
re-install BI tools now VS packages get not visible and Integration package.

Please let me know where i am mistaking in getting all packages in one visual studio environment ?

Comment: Why are you installing a development environment that is 5 years old?

Comment: i used to  work in vs2013 / 2012